# Angular Material App Layout

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Trying to make a kind of 'master-detail' layout with angular material in an electron app.

kinda like this:

[image: mock up with MDL]

I have a toolbar that i want always pinned to the top, and 2 'columns' that should scroll independently, and are full height (minus the height of the toolbar...)

But despite tries putting md-content tags in different places, and messing with css display and positioning... i havent been able to nail this!

[image: nasty scroll behaviors]

what is the 'right' (read: angular material) way to do this? it's gotta have something to do with flexbox css somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/NRELAz)

The main things to point out are

- `layout-fill` and `layout="column"` in the top `div`
- `overflow: auto` for the content

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column">
  <md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings" ng-disabled="true">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <h2>
        <span>Toolbar with Disabled/Enabled Icon Buttons</span>
      </h2>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/favorite.svg" style="color: greenyellow;"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/more_vert.svg"></md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content layout="row" flex>
    <md-list id="list" flex="20">
      <md-list-item
                    class="md-3-line"
                    ng-repeat="item in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
                    ng-click="null">
        <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
          <h3>Hello world</h3>
          <h4>Blah blah</h4>
          <p>123456789</p>
        </div>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
    <md-tabs md-border-bottom flex="80">
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="tabContent" class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="tabContent" class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
          <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
          <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="tabContent" class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#list {
  border-right: 1px solid #DDD;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tabContent {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: this totally worked... i had some kinks to work out, but thans so much for this!